# crossAxisAlignment.stretch making everything invisible

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to align stretch my buttons on the Card child but somehow it is making everything invisible
The main problem is I want the buttons to be evenly matched on their width.

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'loginemail.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  MyApp({this.title});
  final Widget title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        // height: 56.0, // in logical pixels
        // padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        // decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue[500]),
        // Row is a horizontal, linear layout.

        );
  }
}

class MyScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Material is a conceptual piece of paper on which the UI appears.
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('images/boracay.jpg'), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        // Column is a vertical, linear layout.

        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Card(
              child: Container(
                  child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(14.0, 32.0, 14.0, 14.0),
                child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,

                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[

                    Text(
                      'Test',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.greenAccent,fontSize: 32.0),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 32.0,),

                    RaisedButton(child: Row(children: <Widget>[Text('Login'),Icon(Icons.input)],),onPressed: (){},),
                    RaisedButton(child : Row(children: <Widget>[Text('Sign Up'),Icon(Icons.create)],),onPressed: (){},),
                    RaisedButton(child : Row(children: <Widget>[Text('Google Log In'),Icon(Icons.create)],),onPressed: (){},)
                  ],
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                ),
              )),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'My app', // used by the OS task switcher
    home: MyScaffold(),
  ));
}
```

For now I set it to [start] as my widgets become invisible when it is on stretch.
I also added a background image but I don't know if that is the reason why the stretch is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stretching something without boundary, that's why the widgets don't know exactly how big they should stretch. What you need to do is simply adding a value to width property of Container holding the Column.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Card(
            child: Container(
              /// Changes happen here.
              width: 300.0,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(14.0, 32.0, 14.0, 14.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Test',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.greenAccent,
                      fontSize: 32.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 32.0),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[Text('Login'), Icon(Icons.input)],
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[Text('Sign Up'), Icon(Icons.create)],
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Google Log In'),
                        Icon(Icons.create)
                      ],
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```